# Clientside Javascript in Typescript Express projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I always wondered how I can properly add the clientsided javascript in my express project. I use Typescript and I would also like to take advantage of the Typescript typings (for jquery for instance) when writing my clientside javascripts.

**My project structure looks like this:**

- root

  - dist
  - src

    - helpers
    - models
    - registration

      - router.ts
      - form.pug
    - profile

      - router.ts
      - profile.pug
  - wwwroot

    - css
    - js
    - images

**What I have done until today:**

I created all clientsided javascript files in `wwwroot/js` (e.g. jquery.min.js, registration-form.js) and I loaded them into the header of the appropriate pages.

**Disadvantages:**

1. I had to write ES5 javascript which is compatible with the browsers we would like to support
2. I couldn't put the javascript files where they logically belong to (e. g. I'd rather put my `registration-form.js` into `src/registration/` instead of the wwwroot)
3. No Typescript possible :(. No typescript typings, no transpiling to ES5 etc.

In some tutorials I saw they would simply run `npm install --save jquery` and import it in their clientsided files. So I feel like I must have missing some pretty important stuff, but I couldn't find any tutorials about it.

**My question:**

What is the "right way / best practice" to write clientsided javascript in Typescript / Express applications (which should also elliminate also the mentioned disadvantages)?

Comment: This page starts out with the extreme basics but he gets to the part about using Typescript in a node express app. You may find it useful. http://brianflove.com/2016/11/08/typescript-2-express-node/

Comment: @ChrisSharp That article doesn't answer my question at all, as he's not implementing a single line clientsided javascript. And that's what the whole question is about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using TypeScript on the client side is not much different from the server side.

Here is what you can do:

- Create `client` folder for client-side typescript sources
- Put `tsconfig.json` into `client` folder and configure it to produce "es5" code (target: es5)
- Install jquery types (npm install --save-dev @types/jquery)

That's it, now you can write your client side code in TypeScript.

You can compile server-side code with `tsc -p ./src` (having server-side tsconfig.json under `src`) and compile client-side code with `tsc -p ./client`.

I made a simple example of such app, [check it here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/nodejs-typescript). I put the simple script to build everything into package.json, so you can run `npm run-script complie` to get both server and client code complied into `/dist` folder. Then run it with `npm start`.

Further steps:

- Automate your flow: you should be able to start your app locally and then just edit source TypeScript files and the app should be reloaded automatically. This can be done with webpack / gulp / grunt or custom shell script that can be triggered once any of your source file has been changed and saved.
- If you find yourself writing good amount of client-side code, check also angular (https://angular.io/docs). It uses TypeScript as preferred language for client-side development and you'll be able to build much more powerful client-side app using it. You may choose another library as well (react, vue.js, etc), see the [examples on the TypeScript site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/samples/).